# Disk partitions are not appearing separately when installing Ubuntu along with Windows 8.1

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, ubuntu-12.04

I have installed windows 8.1 and now I want to install Ubuntu 12.04 along with it and want dual boot OS. I have 250 GB HD and they partitioned in four drives in windows and in which one is 20 GB portion for Linux which is empty.

But when I am installing Ubuntu with boot-able pen-drive it shows me three drives one system reserved(windows-300 MB of windows), one C: drive(of windows) and other 200 GB combined drive. So how can I solve this??

Comment: Are you using MBR or GPT?  There is a limit of 4 partitions when dealing with MBR partitions.

Comment: I am using MBR.

Comment: Linux requires more then a single partition to install anyways.  So you have other problems besides the partition you want to use not being listed.